# Constructing types with related fields in Julia

Tags: types, constructor, julia

I would like to create a Julia type that contains fields which have a fixed relationship to each other.  For illustration, consider a Point type which represents a point in 2 dimensions, and which has fields representing both its Cartesian (x,y) and polar (r,theta) coordinates.  These fields must be related by r*cos(theta)=x and r*sin(theta)=y, and you should be able to construct a Point by specifying either set of coordinates.  The question is: What's a good way to make a constructor for this type?

Comment: What about just storing it one way and having a function which gives the coordinates in the other form?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas In general (for types more sophisticated than the Point example I gave), the relationship between the fields may be complicated and costly to compute.  It is better to compute it once and have it permanently associated with the object.

Comment: It's not that simple because maybe memory is the bigger requirement, so as always, it depends on the application. For you need, then you can write these functions and just use them in the constructor. What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 4):

If you're happy to introduce 'sub'types, then you can do something like:

```julia
type Cartesian
  x::Float64;  y::Float64
end

type Polar
  r::Float64;  t::Float64
end

type Point
  x::Float64;  y::Float64
  r::Float64;  t::Float64
end

# secondary external constructors
Point(c::Cartesian) = Point(c.x, c.y, sqrt(c.x^2+c.y^2), atan2(c.y, c.x))
Point(p::Polar) = Point(p.r * cos(p.t), p.r * sin(p.t), p.r, p.t)
Point(x::Float64, y::Float64) = Point(Cartesian(x,y))   # ... etc
```

Alternatively, and with regard to Chris' comment, one way to get the best of both worlds, is to create a closure-generating function, instead of a straightforward conversion function, such that once it has been initialised it retains state and can be used to return the conversion to polar at no cost.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible implementation:

```julia
abstract CoordSys
abstract Cartesian <: CoordSys
abstract Polar <: CoordSys

transform(r, theta, ::Type{Polar}) = r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta)
transform(x, y, ::Type{Cartesian}) = sqrt(x^2+y^2), atan2(y, x)

immutable Point{T<:AbstractFloat}
    x::T
    y::T
    r::T
    theta::T
    function Point(x, y, r, theta)
        x_ctrl, y_ctrl = transform(r, theta, Polar)
        if isapprox(x_ctrl, x, atol = 1e-15) && isapprox(y_ctrl, y, atol = 1e-15)
            new(x, y, r, theta)
        else
            error("Coordinates are inconsistent")
        end
     end
 end

 # These constructors take the coordinate system as an additional argument
 Point{T<:AbstractFloat}(x::T, y::T, C::Type{Cartesian}) = Point{T}(x, y, transform(x,y,C)...)
 Point{T<:AbstractFloat}(r::T, theta::T, C::Type{Polar}) = Point{T}(transform(r,theta,C)..., r, theta)

 # Convenience methods
 Point{C<:CoordSys}(x::Real, y::Real, ::Type{C}) = Point(promote(float(x), float(y))..., C)
 Point(x, y) = Point(x, y, Cartesian)
```

It uses an inner constructor to enforce the relations on construction and an `immutable` type to enforce them also after construction.